# Beautifulsoup `<br>` tag handling from input

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

In my html I have a lot of `<br>` tags (unclosed). A test html is the following:

```
html = r"<html><head><title>s</title></head><body>something <br> <b> another thing</b> " \
       r"<br> even more <br> <b> end</b></body></html>"
```

This is a correct html usage right? Simple and "dated", but still legal?

Now I notice that beatifulsoup transforms this html in a real mess, instead of having a "flat tree with only 1 layer of depth below `<body>`" it becomes many layers deep, making analysis cumbersome. Displaying the html also shows this:

```
html = r"<html><head><title>s</title></head><body>something <br> <b> another thing</b> " \
       r"<br> even more <br> <b> end</b></body></html>"
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
print(soup)
```

> output: `<html><head></head><body>something <br> <b> another thing</b>
>    <br> even more <br> <b> end</b></br></br></br></body></html>`

This behaviour changes if I use "html5lib" - at which point the output becomes (which I actually wish to get):

> output: `<html><head></head><body>something <br/> <b> another thing</b>
>    <br/> even more <br/> <b> end</b></body></html>`

Now while html5lib "fixes" the problem, that still is not as I wish it to be: I am providing legal `html` code right? Then why do different parsers give different results?

Comment: This has been reported (by you?) as a bug in BeautifulSoup: https://bugs.launchpad.net/beautifulsoup/+bug/1676935

Answer (score 1):

You can check the difference between the parsers [here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers).

`html5lib` tries to fix your document if its not in a valid format by reading it like a browser does, it is the best option if you want to print a well formed HTML document.

`lxml`does the same thing, but it is faster. By a lot.

The default parser won't serve for this purpose, if you want to use it'll for simple operations it work just fine, you want to maintain the structure of your document, use the parsers mentioned above.

And as stated by `BS`:

> There are also differences between HTML parsers. If you give Beautiful Soup a perfectly-formed HTML document, these differences won’t matter. One parser will be faster than another, but they’ll all give you a data structure that looks exactly like the original HTML document.
>   But if the document is not perfectly-formed, different parsers will give different results.

Comment: Apart from the "doctype declaration" w3's validator sees above HTML line as perferctly-formed: yet the differences DO matter.

Comment: For the default parser, `<br>` is not the same as `<br/>`. When printing the document he will try to close it as he thinks that tag is invalid.

Comment: Non the less, you are right the document is valid, the html.parser doesn't "think" the same way, that is why that in this case `lxml`or `html5lib` are better options.